# sqlite table for json android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have a problem as I don't know how to do this. My project shows basketball tips. It has such combination of levels: Main Category, exercises `ListView` and the next one is details.

Now I need to create an sqlite database for this Json. Do I need to create 2 tables for Json below or it is enough to use only one? Also, does anyone know where can find similar example of my problem?

```
{
    "Basketball":[
    {
        "ids":1,
            "category":"Shooting",
            "catThumb":"http://cbssports.com/images/visual/whatshot/USATSI_8176966.jpg",
            "exercises":[
        {
            "id":1,
                "name":"Shooting drills",
                "thumb":
            "http://app.akharinkhabar.ir/AndroidOnlineNewsImage.aspx?id=7531955",
                    "description":"good clips of Steph Curry's real summer workout..",
                "video":"GkcHK11xpLs",
                "body":"good clips of Steph Curry's real summer workout.."
        },
        {
            "id":2,
                "name":"Shooting drills 2",
                "thumb":
            "https://kycapitalliving.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/basketball-thumbnail.jpg",
                    "description":
            "Today I wanted to go over my favorite three point basketball shooting drills.",
                    "video":"iPNHkpO-vkw",
                "body":
            "Today I wanted to go over my favorite three point basketball shooting drills."
        },
        {
            "id":3,
                "name":"Shooting drills 3",
                "thumb":
            "http://newsletter.newington.nsw.edu.au/wyvern/files/2013/09/basketball-thumbnail.jpg",
                    "description":
            "If every basketball player worked as hard as me. I would get out of my job.",
                    "video":"UyYzhpgi2TA",
                "body":
            "If every basketball player worked as hard as me. I would get out of my job."
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ids":2,
            "category":"Ball Handling",
            "catThumb":
        "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/dd/56/43/dd56432838af2a583a6c22525bf5a18e.jpg",
                "exercises":[
        {
            "id":1,
                "name":"Shooting drills",
                "thumb":
            "http://app.akharinkhabar.ir/AndroidOnlineNewsImage.aspx?id=7531955",
                    "description":
            "good clips of Steph Curry's real summer workout.. ball handling using ropes, floaters,resistance bands, 2 balls drills, vertimax",
                    "video":"MPIuB0rRgsM",
                "body":
            "good clips of Steph Curry's real summer workout.. ball handling using ropes, floaters,resistance bands, 2 balls drills, vertimax"

        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: try this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292335/denoting-multi-dimensional-array-data-in-relational-database-table

Comment: Best way is to store it as string in a table, fetch it and convert it to json  using GSon library to use it whenever needed.

Comment: @Sanoop don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create 2 tables. One for exercise category with columns: ids, category, catThumb and another for exercises with columns id, name, thumb, description, video, body and id from exercise category table to later join this two tables in select queries.

Comment: matejko219 Thank you for your answer. Btw, do you know how can I select all id of exercises by each category ids in sqlite?

Comment: If you know SQL you can use `rawQuery` method to definie custom query. You just need to join these two tables by exercise category id and select these rows where exercise category id equals your desired value.

Comment: `String query = "SELECT * FROM exercise e INNER JOIN exercise_category ec ON e.cat_id=ec.id WHERE ec.id=?";

int category_id;//varaible with id
db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{String.valueOf(category_id)});`